# Does SLsmg_Char_Type represent bytes of the screen?

Tags: c, s-lang

Who has used the `S-lang` library - how the system used this structure? Does each byte of the screen is represented by this struct? I use the library `newt` and the last one used `S-lang`.

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int nchars;
    SLwchar_Type wchars[SLSMG_MAX_CHARS_PER_CELL]; 
    SLsmg_Color_Type color;
} SLsmg_Char_Type;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each *cell* of the screen (not "byte") is represented by `SLsmg_Char_Type`.

- A "cell" is the data at a given row and column.
- A "byte" is typically 8-bits (much smaller than this structure).

The documentation for [SLsmg_char_at](http://multivac.fatburen.org/localdoc/slang/text/cslang.txt) says this:

```
 int SLsmg_char_at(SLsmg_Char_Type *ch);
    Returns the character and its attributes at the current
    position.  The SLsmg_Char_Type object is a structure
    representing the character cell:

          #define SLSMG_MAX_CHARS_PER_CELL 5
          typedef struct
           {
              unsigned int nchars;
              SLwchar_Type wchars[SLSMG_MAX_CHARS_PER_CELL];
              SLsmg_Color_Type color;
           }
           SLsmg_Char_Type;
```